# PHP PDF parser SMALOt and TCPDF Parser

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, tcpdf

I used to get meta data of PDF File. I parsed file using SMALOT pdf Parser and TCPDF Parser.

I parse pdf file using smalot pdf parse and then get metadata and content of pdf file using TCPDF parser Library . Its working for small pdf file but when I parsed 10 MB or large pdf file Memory limit exhuasted and execution stop and not getting any error . I set memory limit 1024M .

```
public function parseFile($filename)
{
  return $this->parseContent($filename);
 }
 public function parseContent($filename)
    {
        // Create structure using TCPDF Parser.
        ob_start();
        $parser = new \TCPDF_PARSER(file_get_contents($filename));
        list($xref, $data) = $parser->getParsedData();
//            print_r($tcpdf->getParsedData());
//            $parser = new \TCPDF_PARSER(ltrim($content));

        list($xref, $data) = $parser->getParsedData();
        unset($parser);
        ob_end_clean();

        if (isset($xref['trailer']['encrypt']))
        {
            throw new \Exception('Secured pdf file are currently not supported.');
        }

        if (empty($data))
        {
            throw new \Exception('Object list not found. Possible secured file.');
        }

        // Create destination object.
        $document = new Document();
        $this->objects = array();

        foreach ($data as $id => $structure)
        {
            $this->parseObject($id, $structure, $document);
            unset($data[$id]);
        }

        $document->setTrailer($this->parseTrailer($xref['trailer'], $document));
        $document->setObjects($this->objects);

        return $document;
    }
```

Comment: what is your question / problem? which part of that code does not work as you intended?

Comment: I parse pdf file using smalot pdf parse and then get metadata and content of pdf file using TCPDF parser Library . Its working for small pdf file  but when I parsed 10 MB or large pdf file Memory limit exhuasted and execution stop and not getting any error . I set memory limit 1024M .